# horizontally scroll table in Angular md-content

Tags: angularjs, scroll, angular-material

In Angular 1.5 I have a table in an `<md-content>`. I dynamically add columns to the table, and at a certain point horizontal scrollbars appear. This is good.

But the bad part is that the new columns are not visible. How could I programmatically scroll my `<md-content>` horizontally so that new columns are visible?

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: Using [angular-scroll-glue](https://github.com/Luegg/angularjs-scroll-glue) is a choice. You can attacth `scroll-glue-right="glued"` to your `md-content` and it shoulds work. I can make a plunker if this suit for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I post in a comment, here you have a [working plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/yEPIohFHSmrGaEswWp1i?p=preview) using [angular-scroll-glue](https://github.com/Luegg/angularjs-scroll-glue) directive.

The key here is attaching `scroll-glue-right` directive to your `md-content`.

```
<md-content scroll-glue-right>
  ...
</md-content>
```

See complete code **[here](https://plnkr.co/edit/yEPIohFHSmrGaEswWp1i?p=preview)**

***EDIT***: If you want to scroll programatically instead  of automatically like in the first plunker, you can bind `scroll-glue-right` to a controller attribute. Example:

```
<md-content scroll-glue-right="glued">
...
</md-content>
```

When `glued` is set to `true`, scroll will be fired.
Working plunker **[here](https://plnkr.co/edit/n3jfW94xXh8MRIkY0GVz?p=preview)**

Hope it helps

Comment: This seems to work nicely, thanks! One note: I see you named the module `luegg.directives` but I don't see any other directives there. Any reason why you didn't just name this module `scroll-glue`?

Comment: Hi @Garret Wilson!glad to help and thanks for the bounty. I just follow the usage guide of the angularjs-sceoll-glue (need to import luegg.directives to use it). I think you can name your module whatever you want but you need to import the directive as luegg.directives.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I thought it was your directive! I'll give my feedback on the `angular-scroll-glue` project then.

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked into [`scrollLeft`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollLeft)? You can get the position of the scrolled element, and then scroll the parent to that position:

```
container.scrollLeft = childToScrollTo.getBoundingClientRect().left;
```

You could certainly build this into a directive if you needed to, or you can just run something like this after you add a column. Here's a quick demo:

```js
var scroll = function(){
  var container = document.getElementById('container');
  var childToScrollTo = document.getElementById('scrollto');
  
  container.scrollLeft = childToScrollTo.getBoundingClientRect().left;
}
```

```css
#container{
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: auto;
  width: 400px;
}

.child{
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="scroll()">scroll</button>
<div id="container">
  <div class="child">child</div>
  <div class="child">child</div>
  <div class="child">child</div>
  <div class="child">child</div>
  <div class="child">child</div>
  <div class="child">child</div>
  <div class="child">child</div>
  <div class="child">child</div>
  <div class="child">child</div>
  <div class="child">child</div>
  <div class="child">child</div>
  <div class="child">child</div>
  <div class="child">child</div>
  <div class="child" id="scrollto">scroll here!</div>
  <div class="child">child</div>
  <div class="child">child</div>
  <div class="child">child</div>
  <div class="child">child</div>
  <div class="child">child</div>
  <div class="child">child</div>
  <div class="child">child</div>
  <div class="child">child</div>
  <div class="child">child</div>
  <div class="child">child</div>
  <div class="child">child</div>
  <div class="child">child</div>
</div>
```